# Removing blank entries from table with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of inputs that I run calculations on. Having empty rows in that table affects the calculations. Right now I have a macro that sorts the table everytime there's any changes made, because of which all the blank rows collect at the bottom of the table. So I just have to resize the table manually before every calculation.

You can see an empty row at the bottom of the table here. I don't know how to go about removing it such that the table ends with last non empty entry

[image]

But I want to know if there's a way to snap the table grid back to the last non empty row using VBA and remove the empty rows from the table. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your code to see what you have done so far and where you are facing problem?

Comment: @Bharat The rest of the code is doing what it's supposed to do. I have  added a screenshot of the table to show you what I want it to do. I haven't written any code for it because I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: see if the posted anser helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next `Sub`. It will delete all table empty rows after filtering. I mean the last (empty) ones:

```
Private Sub deleteTableEmptyRows(Optional TblD As Range) 'calculate table last empty rows
   Dim lastShER As Long, lastShTblR As Long, lastTblER As Long, lastTblR As Long
   
   If TblD Is Nothing Then Set TblD = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
   lastShER = TblD.cells(TblD.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1 'last empty row on the sheet (no needed, only to demonstrate how to calculate)
     lastTblER = lastShER - (TblD.row - 1)                     'last empty row on the table DataBodyRange
   lastShTblR = TblD.rows.count + TblD.row                     'last table row on the sheet
     lastTblR = lastShTblR - TblD.row                          'last table row
   If lastTblER > 1 Then TblD.rows(lastTblER & ":" & lastTblR).Select 'please, change Select with Delete, only after checking that selected range is as you need
End Sub
```

It can be called in this way:

```
Sub testDeleteTableEmptyRows()
    Dim TblD As Range
     Set TblD = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange 'use here the table name (or index)
     deleteTableEmptyRows TblD
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello again! Thanks for the response, I think I can understand how this would work but I'm having a little trouble understanding the variables even with the comments, sorry. Can you please walk me through what the value would be for each variable for the screenshot I shared if the table ranges from Row 2 to Row 6. Thanks again!

Comment: @Wren I would do it if your picture would be elocvent... I cannot see the sheet columns and rows headers, so I do not know if the table in discussion starts from first row, first column or not. That's why my code is able to deal with a table situated anywhere in the sheet. That's why I kept two unnecessary variables, only to show you the mechanism of rows calculation. Can you specify what looks unclear in the above code, having all relevant lines commented... An I will try to be more precise.

Comment: my bad, I have made edits. So the table ranges from Row 2 to Row 7 when I need it to end on Row 6.

Comment: @Wren I would suggest you the last way of testing, learning: Make the VBE (Visual Basic for Application Editor) window smaller, to see the table on the sheet. Click inside the `testDeleteTableEmptyRows` Sub code and press `F8`, to run the code line by line. When the code reaches the function lines, move the cursor over each variable to see its value. You will firstly see the sheet first empty row number, then the table DataBodyRange first empty row, followed by last table row on the sheet (in your case 7) and last DataBodyRange row. You can also insert `Debug.Print lastShER` or other variable.

Comment: @Wren I will try commenting the code and, for testing reason to replace `Delete` with `Select`, in order to play with the code many times, without needing to insert some empty rows.

Comment: @Wren Please, test the updated code. I hope to be clearer, even for somebody not very experienced in VBA... I would need some feedback.

Comment: Actually I am familiar with debug.print. It's the reason I've got anywhere with vba in the past week. But for some reason I couldn't press F8 for this sub so I thought maybe if I understood the variables better I would be able to make changes. But I understand now why I couldn't use F8. The sub requires an input. So I've taken out "TblD As Range" out of the brackets. But I'm not completely sure on how to define TblD inside the sub instead.  Can I use Set TblD = Range("Valve_List") ? Valve_List is the name of the table I'm working with.

Comment: @Wren You missed this part of my comment: **Click inside the testDeleteTableEmptyRows Sub code and press F8**, followed by **When the code reaches the function lines,...**. You cannot use it inside a sub waiting a parameter, because the parameter does not exist and it cannot be processed...

Comment: sorry I did try that first but moved to the other sub because I couldn't pin down the syntanx for defining TblD. I tried looking at examples of usage of databodyrange online but I can't figure it out. Is       ActiveSheet.Listobjects(1).Valve_List.DataBodyRange       close to the right way of writing it?

Comment: @Wren I used a generic way of table setting... I wrote there "'use here the table name (or index)". If there are only a single table on that sheet, it work. Otherwise, you should use `Set TblD = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("YourTableName").DataBodyRange`... Clicking somewhere in the table, the tab `Table Design` becomes visible. Click on it and in its left side, bellow 'Table name:' label you will see its name...

Comment: I had to try this on a different example to understand it better, please let me know if I'm wrong. I'm going to call the variables A, B, C, D in respective order for my clarity. So variable A returns the row number of the first empty row in THE SHEET. The variable B returns the first empty row of THE TABLE (this is a distinction I was struggling with). Variable C returns the first row after the table (IN THE SHEET). Variable D returns the last row (also empty) IN THE SHEET. So if we use TblD.Rows on B and D we get their row numbers on the sheet. Is this accurate?

Comment: There's another issue I need help with. The code works, that much i can see. But in the case of no empty rows in the table, it selects the entire  table and deletes it. Is there a way I can pass a conditional statement for the presence of Blank rows in the table? If present, then run the code, else nothing.

Comment: @Wren OK. I will adapt the code to **select** the range to be deleted, **only** if there is at least a row keeping data. I will adapt the above code according to my statement.

Comment: @Wren Adapted. Is it something else to be adapted, to consider that the above solution answers your question?

Comment: No this is perfec.t Sorry for the late response. I'd written an if condition for the program myself but mine was particular to my sheet because I know the position of the table so I can predict the values of the variables. Your solution is a lot more general. Thank you, I learned a lot from our discussion!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the VBA function that would delete the empty rows

```
Public Sub DeleteBlankRows()
    Dim LastRowIndex As Integer
    Dim RowIndex As Integer
    Dim UsedRng As Range
 
    Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    LastRowIndex = UsedRng.Row - 1 + UsedRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    For RowIndex = LastRowIndex To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountA(Rows(RowIndex)) = 0 Then
            Rows(RowIndex).Delete
        End If
    Next RowIndex
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here is sample

[image]

And this is how it looks after
[image]

Comment: this will delete even the data is not sorted

Answer (score 2):

### Delete Blank Rows in an Excel Table

- No need to sort the table if you don't want to.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteTableBlankRows()
    
    With Sheet1.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
        
        Dim cCount As Long: cCount = .Columns.Count
        
        Dim drg As Range ' Delete Range
        Dim rrg As Range ' Row Range
        
        For Each rrg In .Rows
            If Application.CountBlank(rrg) = cCount Then
                If drg Is Nothing Then
                    Set drg = rrg
                Else
                    Set drg = Union(drg, rrg)
                End If
            End If
        Next rrg
        
        If Not drg Is Nothing Then
            drg.Delete
        End If
    
    End With
            
End Sub
```